# Discord.py bot doesn't respond to commands but does on mentions

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have a problem with my discord.py bot. Here's a part of the code:

```
import os, discord
from discord.ext import commands
from flask import Flask
from threading import Thread

PREFIX = '/'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=PREFIX)


app = Flask('')

@app.route('/')
def main():
  return 'Bot is ready!'

def run():
  app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)

def keep_alive():
  server = Thread(target=run)
  server.start()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
    await message.channel.send(embed=infoEmbed) #infoEmbed is defined

@client.command()
async def test(ctx, txt):
  await ctx.send('You said ' + txt)

keep_alive()
client.run(os.environ['bot_token'])
```

I run the code, but it doesn't respond to commands, just on mentions. I cannot find the bug. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think I know. You made the prefix “/“. Discord recently added a feature where bots could respond to / commands, but only if you add certain code I believe. Try using a new prefix? If that helps let me know.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).